# What is Exclusive Mode in VMWare?

Tags: vmware

So what exactly is exclusive mode in VMWare?  I see that when I use it it puts me in to full screen basically.  But is there any other benefit than just aesthetic reasons?

Does Exclusive Mode make it so that the virtual machine runs on a higher priority on the processor?  I guess what I'm trying to find out is **if there are any performance benefits in running in Exclusive Mode**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exclusive mode changes two things:

1. It gives the guest control over the system display resolution(s).
2. It removes any VMWare "toolbars" and such -- it makes the guest OS behave as if it were the OS, rather than a full screen guest. You don't have to worry about the guest losing focus if exclusive mode is on, other than the "Secure Attention Sequence/Three Finger Salute/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>" and the "breaking key combination" you set (which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> by default).

Comment: Right, I already noticed these behaviors.  But more specifically I wanted to know if there are any performance benefits in using exclusive mode.

Comment: @FooBook: Then the answer is "no" :) See Page 164 of the [VMWare Workstation Manual](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/ws_pubs.html) -> "You might want to use exclusive mode to run graphics‐intensive applications, such as
games, in full screen mode."